# Why do answers need to be copy-pasted from other sites?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

With regards to:
[Why was my answer deleted? And why didn't I get an explanation for the deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189283/why-was-my-answer-deleted-and-why-didnt-i-get-an-explanation-for-the-deletion)

The link fully answered the question right from the boost documentation.
What is wrong with it?

Comment: They should ***not*** be copy-pasted from other sites.

Answer (score 8):

> What is wrong with it?

Because your answer will become invalid/obsolete once that link is expired. So linking in your answer is not discouraged here but *only linking* is discouraged which you did in your answer.

You really need to look at:

- [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/187824)
- [Answering technical questions helpfully by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx)

Comment: Just to add for posterity's sake, there's another good reason: Stack Overflow is here to be a searchable repository of good questions and answers, rather than a collection of links. One could even think of it as self-serving, in a way; We're not looking to help other sites get more traffic, but to get good content to bring it *here*!